# Deliverable two: connecting instance

Tags: instance

I am in the process of trying to connect my instance on my macbook, but it keeps saying "no such file or directory". If someone can help me on this I would appreciate it.

I attached below how I am starting it, but I am not sure if I am doing it wrong or not. My key is also dowloaded, but it says it cannot find it.

Here is the code:

```
Last login: Thu Jun 11 14:09:36 on ttys000
Julias-MacBook:~ julia$ /users/julia/.../Julia.pem
-bash: /users/julia/.../Julia.pem: No such file or directory
Julias-MacBook:~ julia$
```

Comment: hi. you need to provide more context on what you're working on. for example: an instance of what?

Comment: You seem to be trying to execute a certificate as a command. Please add tags for the software you are trying to use. A more detailed description of what you are trying to do also wouldn't hurt.